# Finding an exe from any hard drive and setting it as a variable

Tags: batch, environment-variables, ffprobe

I have a way to find an exe file from any drive without needing to play with %path%, but I need it set as a path-to-file variable, not just displayed.

```
for %i in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do @%i: 2>nul && dir /s ffprobe.exe
```

Any of the resulting files could be set as the variable (like the last one), but the latest (by date or version) would be optimal.

--- more info for additional question ---

```
for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    @%%d: 2>nul && for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`dir /s /b ffprobe.exe`) do set "probe=%%f" && goto done
)
```

This is the version I built using the answer. For some reason it fails to capture the whole path-to-file when there is a space somewhere in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve your code:

Use `dir /s /b` to get just the bare file-name.

To get the result of the `dir` command into the variable,
use an inner loop like that:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`dir /s /b ffprobe.exe`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%
```

Comment: @harrymc That works nicely! Instead of looking up the latest date version, I could just trust the one found in earlier drives like C: instead of later ones which might be archive or backup drives. How would I make it stop at the first found?

Comment: Use a [goto command](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) to break out of the loop.

Comment: @harrymc Please check the added info in the OP. It cuts off the rest of the path-to-file if there is a space present even though quotes are used.

Comment: Use "delims=" to place everything on the line into the variable. See https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html.

Answer (score 1):

> *Any of the resulting files could be set as the variable (like the last one), but the latest (by date or version) would be optimal.*
>
> - To scan all drivers:

```bath
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set "_f=" && set "_ff=" && set /a "_cnt=0" 
for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%f in (`%__AppDir__%mountvol.exe^|find.exe /i ":\"
    `)do 2>nul pushd %%~f && (set/a "_cnt+=1" && call %:^) _ff_!_cnt! & popd)
    
for /f useback^tokens^=1*delims^=^=^  %%i in (`^<nul ^<con: set _ff_^|%__AppDir__%sort.exe /r
    `)do <con: <nul call set "_ffprobe=%%~dpnxj" & call set "_ffprob_Path=%%~dpj" & goto %:^|
 
%:^)
for /f usebackq^tokens^=2^,4* %%i in =;(`2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe /r \ ffprobe.exe /t ^|^
    %__AppDir__%sort.exe /r^|^|exit/b`)do set "_f=%%~k" && for /f useback^delims^=. %%G in (`
        ^<con %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe DataFile where name^="!_f:\=\\!" get LastModified ^|^
            %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /rb [0-9]`)do <con: <nul call set "%~1=%%~k" && exit /b 0

%:^|
<con: rem.// your code continues at this point using: & echo+!_ffprobe! & echo+!_ffprob_Path!
```

---

> - To limit to only in Local Disk  (`DriveType=3 == HD's`):

```bath
@echo off

=====setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set/a "_cnt=0" & call set _ff=<nul & call set _f=<nul
for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i In (`%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe LogicalDisk where DriveType^='3'^
    get caption^|find ":"`)do pushd %%~i && (set/a "_cnt+=1" && call %:^) _ff_!_cnt! & popd )

for /f useback^tokens^=1*delims^=^=^  %%i in (`^<nul ^<con: set _ff_^|%__AppDir__%sort.exe /r
    `)do <con: <nul call set "_ffprobe=%%~dpnxj" & call set "_ffprob_Path=%%~dpj" & goto %:^|
 
%:^)
for /f usebackq^tokens^=2^,4* %%i in =;(`2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe /r \ ffprobe.exe /t ^|^
    %__AppDir__%sort.exe /r^|^|exit/b`)do set "_f=%%~k" && for /f useback^delims^=. %%G in (`
        ^<con %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe DataFile where name^="!_f:\=\\!" get LastModified ^|^
            %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /rb [0-9]`)do <con: <nul call set "%~1=%%~k" && exit /b 0

%:^|
<con: rem.// your code continues at this point using: & echo+!_ffprobe! & echo+!_ffprob_Path!
```

---

**1.** Get all available drivers

**2.** Scan each validated drive

**3.** Use size-ordered output

**4.** Get the LastModified date

**5.** Save Last Modified date and Path one by one

**6.** Use date inversion and get latest/highest number

---

**Obs.:** Scan each hd, as well as each pen drive, memory card, cd (if any media is present on the drive), keep in mind that it may take some time...

---

## Some further reading:

[√] **[Set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

[√] **[Wmic /?](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)**

[√] **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

[√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

[√] **[MountVol /?](https://ss64.com/nt/mountvol.html)**

[√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

[√] **[Goto :Label /? | Call :Label /?](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**

[√] **[DelayedExpansion (Refer: `!Expand_RunTime_Variable!`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

[√] **[Show all drives from Windows command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/commands/wmic/logicaldisk.php)**

[√] **[`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

**[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**