# How to send variable to a background process, which is a loop :label of the bat itself (or stop loop if variable defined)

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a bat with some label on it, so I start my bat checking if any argument was passed, if not, the execution will make a new call of the bat itself passing an argument, and once that is done it continues executing the next commands.

When bat starts by a call taking an argument, then its execution is looped inside a :label (permanently)

It's a bat that can take a long time to run, so the call causes an "infinite" progress bar to appear in the window title and remains in a loop doing it in background.

[image]

Because it's tedious to see a static line (*"Finding Nemo, Files, etc..."*) either on the screen or in the title bar, and a recent example of a task/ script that takes a long time, is finding a newer executable (version/date) by scanning all drivers and comparing the results to get one (newer), answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1674671/969781).

Taking the code linked above for a time-consuming task example, and adding a progress bar in the title, I have the following code:

```
@echo off

if "%~1."=="." (call start ".:." /b cmd.exe /v:on /c "%~f0" ? )else goto %:^|
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set "_f=" && set "_ff=" && set /a "_cnt=0"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%f in (`%__AppDir__%mountvol.exe^|find.exe /i ":\"
    `)do 2>nul pushd %%~f && (set/a "_cnt+=1" && call %:^) _ff_!_cnt! & popd)

for /f useback^tokens^=1*delims^=^=^ %%i in (`^<nul ^<con: set _ff_ ^|%__AppDir__%sort.exe /r
    `)do <con: <nul call set "_ffprobe=%%~dpnxj" & call set "_ffprob_Path=%%~dpj" & goto %:^V

%:^)
for /f usebackq^tokens^=2^,4* %%i in =;(`2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe /r \ ffprobe.exe /t ^|^
    %__AppDir__%sort.exe /r^|^|exit/b`)do set "_f=%%~k" && for /f useback^delims^=. %%G in (`
        ^<con %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe DataFile where name^="!_f:\=\\!" get LastModified ^|^
            %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /rb [0-9]`)do <con: <nul call set "%~1=%%~k" && exit /b 0

%:^|
>nul chcp 65001 & mode 89,5 & set "_title=Looking for your latest ffprob.exe, please wait^!!"

<con: ;color 0a && set^ "_176=░░░░░░░░░░" && set^ "_255=▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓" && set^ "_022=▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬"
call setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "_ping=%__AppDir__%pathping.exe 127.1 -q 1 -p 050"

%:^/
set "_title=I'm doing something that takes a while, please wait^!!"
for %%G in =;(1,2,3,4,5,6,0)do if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." =;( if ".\%%~G\." == ".\1\." =;(
     for /l %%L in (0 01 10)do %_ping% |title !_title! [!_255:~0,%%~L!!_022:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
    )else if "%%G\" == "2\" =;(if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." =;(
     for /l %%L in (10 -1 0)do %_ping% |title !_title! [!_255:~0,%%~L!!_176:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
   ))else if "%%G\" == "3\" =;(if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." =;(
     for /l %%L in (0 01 10)do %_ping% |title !_title! [!_022:~0,%%~L!!_176:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
   ))else if "%%G\" == "4\" =;(if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." =;(
     for /l %%L in (10 -1 0)do %_ping% |title !_title! [!_022:~0,%%~L!!_255:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
   ))else if "%%G\" == "5\" =;(if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." =;(
     for /l %%L in (0 01 10)do %_ping% |title !_title! [!_176:~0,%%~L!!_255:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
   ))else if "%%G\" == "6\" =;(if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." =;(
     for /l %%L in (10 -1 1)do %_ping% |title !_title! [!_176:~0,%%~L!!_022:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
   ))else if "%%G\" == "0\" =;(if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." =;(
    goto %:^/
   )));= 

%:^V
rem./ your code continues at this point using: / & echo+!_ffprob_Path! & echo+!_ffprobe!
```

The result is that the "infinite" progress bar starts and doesn't stop, even after the variable is set, where it should signal the end of the loop in the progress bar label, but it doesn't work...

[image]

Several attempts were made with enable/disable setlocal, reversing the order of the label call, and things that I don't even remember, but there were several attempts to end the loop and without success...

How to end the loop of a label running in the background of the same bat?

I've been at this point for so long that I don't see anything.

Any idea?

---

The same code in conventional layout...

```
@echo off

if "%~1." == "." (
     call start ".:." /b cmd.exe /v:on /c "%~f0" ? 
    ) else (
     goto %:^p
    )
    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_f="
set "_ff="
set /a "_cnt=0"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`%__AppDir__%mountvol.exe ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe /i ":\"`) do 2>nul (
     pushd %%~f && (
         set /a "_cnt+=1"
         call %:^) _ff_!_cnt!
         popd
        )
    )
    
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%i in (`set _ff_ ^| %__AppDir__%sort.exe /r`) do (
     call set "_ffprobe=%%~dpnxj"
     call set "_ffprob_Path=%%~dpj"
     goto %:^V
    )
 
%:^)
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,4*" %%i in  (`2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe /r \ ffprobe.exe /t ^| %__AppDir__%sort.exe /r ^|^| exit /b`) do (
     set "_f=%%~k"
     for /f "usebackq delims=." %%G in (`^<con: call %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe DataFile where name^="!_f:\=\\!" get LastModified ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /rb [0-9]`)do (
         call set "%~1=%%~k"
         exit /b 0
        )
    )

%:^p
>nul chcp 65001
%__AppDir__%mode.com con: cols=89 lines=5

set "_title=Looking for your latest ffprob.exe, please wait^!!"

color 0a
set "_176=░░░░░░░░░░"
set "_255=▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓"
set "_022=▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_ping=%__AppDir__%pathping.exe 127.1 -q 1 -p 050"

%:^/
for %%G in =;(1,2,3,4,5,6,0)do (
     if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." ( 
        if ".\%%~G\." == ".\1\." (
             for /l %%L in (0 01 10) do %_ping% |  title !_title! [!_255:~0,%%~L!!_022:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
        )else if "%%G\" == "2\" (
             if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." (
                 for /l %%L in (10 -1 0) do %_ping% | title !_title! [!_255:~0,%%~L!!_176:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
                )
        )else if "%%G\" == "3\" (
             if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." (
                 for /l %%L in (0 01 10) do %_ping% | title !_title! [!_022:~0,%%~L!!_176:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
                )
        )else if "%%G\" == "4\" (
             if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." (
                 for /l %%L in (10 -1 0) do %_ping% | title !_title! [!_022:~0,%%~L!!_255:~%%L!] !time:~,8!
                )
        )else if "%%G\" == "5\"  (
             if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." (
                 for /l %%L in (0 01 10) do %_ping% | title !_title! [!_176:~0,%%~L!!_255:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
            )
        )else if "%%G\" == "6\"  (
             if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." (
                 for /l %%L in (10 -1 1) do %_ping% | title !_title! [!_176:~0,%%~L!!_022:~%%L!] !time:~,8! 
            )
        )else if "%%G\" == "0\"  (
            if "!_ffprob_Path!\." == "\." (
                 goto %:^/
                )
            )
        )
    ) 
   
%:^V
rem./ your code continues at this point using: / 
echo+!_ffprob_Path!
echo+!_ffprobe!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to this is to use an infinite for /l loop in a label that is started as a seperate thread. I use an ADS of the file to communicate to the thread from the main file when to stop, then a hard Exit to quit the thread.

```bat
:# Author: T3RRY Created: 03/06/2021
:# Purpose: RGB Spinner animation for load / waiting indication while script continues to run.
:# Utilises a second thread to display animation while the main script continues executing.
:# Execution and termination of the thread is controlled using a value stored in an alternate data
:# stream of this file:. 1 = run ; 0 = stop

@Echo off & CD /D "%~dp0"

:# thread label structure by Jeb - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68636825/12343998
 for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") do goto %%L

 Call :defMacros
 %= Quit if not NTFS =% If Errorlevel 1 Exit /b
 Cls

===:# Usage Examples.
               
 %Start.Thread:MSG=Example 1%
  For /l %%i in (1 1 100000)Do Set "var=%%i"
 %End.Thread%
 Echo([%var%] iterations actioned.

 %Start.Thread:MSG=Example 2%
  For /l %%i in (1 1 10000)Do Set "var=%%i"
 %End.Thread%
 Echo([%var%] iterations actioned.

 %Start.Thread:MSG=Example 3%
 Set "var=1"
 %End.Thread%
 Echo([%var%] iterations actioned.

:# End script cleanup
 Powershell -c "remove-item -path '%~nx0' -Stream '*'"
 CHCP %active.cp% > nul
 @Pause

Goto :Eof

===========================================================
:AnimThread - Animation; RGB or BW spinner
:# Animation sequence. Symbols will not display correctly with certain fonts
:# Recommended font: Lucida Console
:# Alt 205 ═ 186 ║ 187 ╗ 200 ╚ 188 ╝ 201 ╔
:# ╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗
:# ║/║║-║║\║║|║
:# ╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝
:#
:# Framerate: ~ 25 fps. ('Delay' assigned as 4/100ths of a second.)
:# NOTE - Multiple instances of this thread can not be run in parallel;
:#        as Virtual terminal Cursor save operation will overide information stored by parallel threads

 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 CHCP 65001 > nul
 If "%_Param%"=="MSG" Set "_Param=Executing"
 If defined Win10 <nul set /p "=%\E%[1E%_Param%.%\E%[?25l%\E%[1E%\E%7"
 Set "title.i=-1"
 Set "T2[L]=0"         %= Rem Spinner Loop count    =%
 Set "T2[chars]= |/-\" %= Rem Spinner characters    =%
 Set "Delay=4"         %= Framerate in Centiseconds =%

:# frame control via elapsed time by Dave Benham - https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741

 If defined Win10 For /l %%. in ()Do (
  %= Check completion status flagged in status stream of this file; =%
  (For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%G in ("%~f0:Stream")Do if %%G EQU 0 (
   <nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25h%\E%8%\E[K%"                  %= restore cursor    =%
   %restore.CP% > nul                                   %= restore codepage  =%
   <nul Set /P "=%\E%[7;32mCompleted.%\E%[0m%\E%[1E%\E%[M%\E%[K" %= notify completion; Emit newline; Delete last line of animation =%
   (TITLE )
   Exit                                                 %= exit thread       =%
  ))2> nul

  %= Calculate time elapsed =%
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!time: =0!") do set /a "t2=(((1%%a*60)+1%%b)*60+1%%c)*100+1%%d-36610100, tDiff=t2-t1"
  if !tDiff! lss 0 set /a tDiff+=24*60*60*100

  if !tDiff! geq !delay! (
   Set /A title.i+=1
   If !title.i! GTR 9 Set "title.i=0"
   Set "Bar=║0123456789║"
   For /l %%v in (0 1 9)Do If %%v NEQ !title.i! (Set "Bar=!Bar:%%v=░!")Else Set "Bar=!Bar:%%v=▬!"
   Title Processing... !BAR! !Time!
   %= delay has expired ; display frame =%
   Set /A "T2[L]+=1"        %= Increment index point of spinner string =%
   %= Output Spinner frame. Overwites previous output using saved cursor position =%
   For /f "Delims=" %%v in ("!T2[L]!")Do <nul Set /p "=%\E%8%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;150;;150m╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗%\E%[0;38;2;150;;150m%\E%[K%\E%[E║%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;255;;m!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!%\E%[0m%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;150;;150m║║%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;;255;m!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!%\E%[0m%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;150;;150m║║%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;;100;255m!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!%\E%[0m%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;150;;150m║%\E%[0m%\E%[K%\E%[E%\E%[38;2;20;20;20;7m%\E%[48;2;150;;150m╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝%\E%[0m%\E%[K%\E%[1G%\E%[2A%\E%7"
   If !T2[L]! EQU 4 Set "T2[L]=0" %= Reset index point of spinner string =%
   set /a t1=t2
  )
 )

 %= If not defined Win10 [ No Virtual Terminal support ] =%
 For /l %%. in ()Do (
  (For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%G in ("%~f0:Stream")Do if %%G EQU 0 (
   %restore.CP% > nul
   Cls
   Echo(Complete.
   (TITLE )
   Exit
  ))2> nul

  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!time: =0!") do set /a "t2=(((1%%a*60)+1%%b)*60+1%%c)*100+1%%d-36610100, tDiff=t2-t1"
  if !tDiff! lss 0 set /a tDiff+=24*60*60*100

  if !tDiff! geq !delay! (
   Set /A title.i+=1
   If !title.i! GTR 9 Set "title.i=0"
   Set "Bar=║0123456789║"
   For /l %%v in (0 1 9)Do If %%v NEQ !title.i! (Set "Bar=!Bar:%%v=░!")Else Set "Bar=!Bar:%%v=▬!"
   Title Processing... !BAR! !Time!
   Set /A "T2[L]+=1"
   For /f "Delims=" %%v in ("!T2[L]!")Do (
    Cls
    Echo(%_Param%.
    Echo(╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗
    Echo(║!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!║║!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!║║!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!║║!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!║║!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!║║!T2[chars]:~%%v,1!║
    Echo(╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝
   )
   If !T2[L]! EQU 4 Set "T2[L]=0"
   set /a t1=t2
  )
 )

:defMacros
:# OS Requirement tests

:# Verify NTFS drive
 (Echo(verify.NTFS >"%~f0:Status") || (
  Echo(This file must be located on an NTFS drive as it utilises alternate data streams.
  Timeout /t 5
  Exit /B 1
 )

:# Windows Version control. Assigns flag true if system is windows 10 build GTR 10586
:# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#DOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows
:# Version 1511 build number = 10.0.10586
 Set "Win10="
 For /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%v in ('Ver')Do if %%v GTR 10586 Set "Win10=True"

:# If Win10 true ; Test if virtual terminal codes enabled ; enable if false
:# removes win10 flag definition if version does not support Virtual Terminal sequences
 If defined Win10 (
  Reg Query HKCU\Console | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"VirtualTerminalLevel    REG_DWORD    0x1" > nul || (
    Reg Add HKCU\Console /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  ) > Nul || Set "Win10="
 )


=====:# Store codepage to restore on script completion
 For /f "tokens=4 Delims=: " %%1 in ('CHCP')Do Set "active.cp=%%1"

=====:# Define Escape character for Virtual terminal sequences 
If Defined Win10 For /f "Delims=" %%e in ('Echo(Prompt $E^|Cmd')Do Set "\E=%%e"

==================:# macros start and stop Thread via t/f flag written to alternate data stream.
:# Start.Thread - Save current Codepage;
:#                Remove status thread from this file if present;
:#                Notify command has started;
:#                Flag status 1 in Stream :status;
:#                Use start /b with params to relaunch this script and execute second thread
:#                executes infinite loop in AnimThread1 based on win10 virtual terminal support

 Set "Start.Thread=Set "_param=MSG"& (For /F "tokens=2 Delims=:" %%G in ('CHCP')Do Set "restore.CP=CHCP %%G")&((Echo(1)>"%~f0:Stream") & Start /AboveNormal /b "" "%~d0\:AnimThread:\..%~pnx0""

:# End.Thread  - Flag status 0 in Stream :Status;
:#               Execute a small delay to ensure thread has time to enable cursor display and clear animation.
:#               [Delay of approx. 1/66th of a second]

 Set "End.Thread=((Echo(0)>"%~f0:Stream")&For /L %%i in (1 1 750)Do ((Call ))"

Exit /b 0
```

Comment: You and your phenomenal macros... thanks a lot, I'll take it easy later (here it's 6am and I'm still sleeping)... but any tips to treat my theme in the titlebar/loop/lable?

Comment: When you have the opportunity to review the script, you should see easily enough where the animation occurs - just swap out that section for your title animation.  See the included examples of using start.thread and end.thread for how to begin and end the animation  during your scripts execution

Comment: For your specific issue, there needs to be a means of breaking the cycle of restarting the script at the label `^|`. Have you tried using a variable for this part of the control structure and changing `else goto %:^|` to `else if not defined _Somevar (goto %:^|)Else Exit`